# How to configure tempusage in activemq grails app

Tags: grails, activemq-classic

I am using jms to send messages between two apps, here is the code for receiver app

```
xmlns amq:"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"

amq.'broker'(
        useJmx: '${grails.jms.useJmx}',
        persistent:'${grails.jms.persistent}',
        dataDirectory: '${grails.jms.dataDirectory}'){
    amq.'transportConnectors'{
        amq.'transportConnector'(uri:'${grails.jms.transportConnector}')
    }
}

amqConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnectionFactory) {
    brokerURL = '${grails.jms.brokerUrl}'
}

jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory) {  bean ->
    targetConnectionFactory = ref(amqConnectionFactory)
}
```

I am able to run the app but getting error like
    "Store limit is 102400 mb, whilst the data directory: /my-activemq-data/localhost/KahaDB only has 7438 mb of usable space" in console. I just want to configure the temp memory usage, can anyone help me on this. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the https://grails.org/plugin/activemq plugin?
If so, I added precisely that functionality to the plugin.
The plugin allows the following configuration options (just put them in your Config.groovy):

```
grails.activemq.active = (true|false) default to true
grails.activemq.useJms = (true|false) default to false
grails.activemq.startBroker = (true|false) default to true
grails.activemq.brokerId = (string) default to "brokerId"
grails.activemq.brokerName = (string) default to "localhost"
grails.activemq.persistent = (true|false) default to false
grails.activemq.port = (int) default to 61616
grails.activemq.tempUsageLimit = (size in bytes) defaults to 64Mb
grails.activemq.storeUsageLimit = (size in bytes) defaults to 64Mb
```

If you aren't using the plugin maybe you should :)

For reference, this is the resources.groovy file I use for most projects (which rely on an application server jndi based JMS service for test and production and use activemq for development):

```
import grails.util.Environment
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
import org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean

beans = {

    switch(Environment.current) {
        case Environment.PRODUCTION:
        case Environment.TEST:
            jmsConnectionFactory(JndiObjectFactoryBean) {
                jndiName = "java:/ConnectionFactory"
            }
            break

        case Environment.DEVELOPMENT:
            jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory) {
                targetConnectionFactory = { ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf ->
                    brokerURL = 'vm://localhost'
                }
            }
            break
    }
}
```

I had the same problem as you while using ActiveMQ with the activemq plugin, so I made a pull request adding those configuration options and setting them to a more reasonable default (for development) of 64Mb.

If you use the plugin you just need to add it to your BuildConfig plugins section, and it should work ok without further configuration, just the resources.groovy inside config/spring.

Anyway, the options I described should go into Config.groovy if you need any of them.

Comment: Thanks for the information, could you check this this is my config.groovy  grails{
    jms{
        useJmx = false
        persistent = true
        dataDirectory = 'my-activemq-data'
        brokerUrl = 'vm://localhost'
        transportConnector = 'tcp://{IP}:{port}'
    }
}

Comment: I think you're mixing up things. The plugin has no dataDirectory configuration option, not currently as of version 0.5. And some of your options should really be in resources.groovy. I'll update the answer with a sample resources.groovy (the one I use).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got solution to my problem. here is the updated resource.groovy

```
activeMQTempUsage(TempUsage) {
    activeMQTempUsage.limit = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 
}

activeMQStoreUsage(StoreUsage) {
    activeMQStoreUsage.limit = 1024 * 1024 * 1024
}

activeMQSystemUsage(SystemUsage){
    activeMQSystemUsage.tempUsage = ref('activeMQTempUsage')
    activeMQSystemUsage.storeUsage = ref('activeMQStoreUsage')
}

tcpConnector(TransportConnector,uri:'tcp://localhost:61616') {   
}

connectors(ArrayList,[ref('tcpConnector')]){
}

myBrokerService(XBeanBrokerService){bean->
    myBrokerService.useJmx = false
    myBrokerService.persistent = true
    myBrokerService.dataDirectory = 'my-activemq-data'
    myBrokerService.systemUsage = ref('activeMQSystemUsage')
    myBrokerService.transportConnectors = ref('connectors')
}

amqConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnectionFactory) {
    brokerURL = 'vm://localhost'
}

jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory) {  bean ->
    targetConnectionFactory = ref(amqConnectionFactory)
}
```

Using XbeanBrokerService properties we can achieve this, if you we want add more configuration we can add by using properties of XbeanBrokerService as like above.